# Use Azure Data Factory to parse JSON table to csv format

Tags: json, azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I am new to data flows in adf. I have a api response json and I want to convert it to csv format

`{ "headers": [ "SCENARIO", "LOT", "BID_SUBMISSION", "SHARE_AWARDED", "Lot ID", "Price (EUR)" ], "data-rows": [ [ "Low Cost Baseline", "Item 01", "Bidder 1", 1.0, "Item 01", 42.0 ], [ "Low Cost Baseline", "Item 02", "Bidder 2", 1.0, "Item 02", 265.0 ] ] }`

Answer (score -1):

You can convert JSON to CSV format using `flatten` transformation in **ADF data flow**.

1. Connect the Source to the `rest API` dataset and create a linked service connection by providing API details.

[image]

[image]

2. Select the document form as per the source JSON format.

[image]

3. Connect source output to `flatten` transformation to flatten the JSON file. Refer to [Flatten transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) for flattern settings.

[image]

4. Add sink destination to store the JSON file in CSV format by selecting blob storage dataset and CSV format.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> **Note**: You can add multiple flatten/parse transformations between source and sink to get required output.